# ng-if condition with model which is updated using ajax

Tags: angularjs

I have a model in my controller which is updated via asynchronous call through $http. And I am using a flag to check whether my model is defined or not.

```
 function myController(ModelService){
       var vm = this;
       vm.myModel = ModelService.data; // ModelService.data will get updated asynchronously later
       vm.showDetails = typeof vm.myModel !== 'undefined';   //Flag to check whether the model is defined or not
 }
```

HTML,

```
 <div ng-if='MyController.showDetails'>
           ...
 </div>
```

Currently the `div` is not shown even after myModel is populated with proper data later. Could you please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: watch for your model

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
vm.showDetails = typeof vm.myModel !== 'undefined';
```

is executed only once for the controller - and obviously at the time the data are not ready yet. If you are sure that vm.myModel is updated correctly then the following code should work for you:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.myModel', function () {
    vm.showDetails = typeof vm.myModel !== 'undefined';  
}, true);
```

It watches for any changes in the vm.myModel and triggers the code inside each time a change is detected. Please notice that you need to inject the $scope service to your controller, e.g.:

```
function myController(ModelService, $scope) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http` will return a promise so you can use like

```
ModelService.data()
  .then(function(response){
      vm.showDetails = true;
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `$watch` like Anton said. But, given that you will only fetch once, a would recomend making the changes in your model after de return of your service. Your `ModelService` should return a promise, so you should be able to do something like

```
ModelService.data().then(function(response){
    vm.myModel = response;
    vm.showDetails = typeof vm.myModel !== 'undefined';
});
```